# Prove that $(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^3)(1+z+z^4)=z(1+z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

We have $z = \cos(2\pi/5)+i \sin(2\pi/5)$. Prove that:

$(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^3)(1+z+z^4)=z(1+z)$

I noticed that in each bracket contain $(1+z)$, so I let $t$ equal $(1+z)$ to simplify the equation into $(t+z^2)(t+z^3)(t+z^4)=zt$, but I don't know what to do next. I also tried to multiply the parentheses too but then the equation becomes crazier. I hope someone here could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried substituting the value for $Z$ to show that the right-hand side expands into something that is the same as whatever the left-hand side expands into?

Comment: also, it might be helpful to present $Z$ in polar form with $r$ and $\theta$ rather than sine and cosine; i.e. $Z = r e^{i \theta}$

Answer (score 3):

If you actually expand $(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^3)(1+z+z^4) - z(1+z)$ out, you will get:

$$z^9+z^8+2z^7+3z^6+4z^5+4z^4+4z^3+3z^2+2z+1$$
$$=5z^4+5z^3+5z^2+5z+5 \quad \text{(why?)}$$
$$=5 \left( \frac{z^5-1}{z-1} \right)$$
$$=0$$

Therefore $(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^3)(1+z+z^4) = z(1+z)$.

In addition, you can use your idea of making the substitution $t=1+z$, so that way you only have $8$ things to multiply.

Comment: It seems like multiplying all the terms out is the only way to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $z=\cos(2\pi/5)+i\sin(2\pi/5)=e^{2\pi i/5}\not=1$ then $z^5=1$. Therefore, **before** taking the product, we write each factor in a convenient way:
$$\begin{align}
(1+z+z^2)&=\frac{1-z^3}{1-z}=\frac{z^2-1}{z^2(1-z)}=-\frac{1+z}{z^2},\\
(1+z+z^3)&=\frac{z^4(1+z+z^3)}{z^4}=\frac{1+z^2+z^4}{z^4}=\frac{1-z^6}{z^4(1-z^2)}=\frac{z(1-z)}{(1-z^2)}=\frac{z}{1+z},\\
(1+z+z^4)&=\frac{z(1+z+z^4)}{z}=\frac{1+z+z^2}{z}=-\frac{1+z}{z^3}=-z^2(1+z).
\end{align}$$
Putting all together, it follows that
$$(1+z+z^2)(1+z+z^3)(1+z+z^4)=-\frac{1+z}{z^2}\cdot \frac{z}{z+1}\cdot
-z^2(1+z)=z(1+z).$$

Comment: Isn't $\frac{z^2-1}{z^2(1-z)} = -\frac{z+1}{z^2}$?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to prove this holds for a specific value of $z$, just write it in exponential form and substitute.